# Find which coordinate is imaginary in the given list?

Tags: python, sympy

Given the list of coordinates, How to find which coordinate is imaginary in python?

```
ip_coord = [(59.7650000000000, -17.968172555939*I), (59.7650000000000, 17.968172555939*I)]
```

I need to find out the imaginary values from the above set of coordinates,

```
-17.968172555939*I
 17.968172555939*I
```

Which sympy functionality supports the above one?

Comment: You could check every element for its "is_real" attribute. Like ip_coord[0][1].is_real

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want the imaginary (i.e. non-real) values wherever they may be you can flatten the list and test each value:

```
>>> [i for i in Tuple(*flatten(ip_coord)) if i.is_real is False]
[-17.968172555939*I, 17.968172555939*I]
```

(The `Tuple` is not needed if you are already working with SymPy values; but if you copy and past what you have shown you will need it in order to handle the Floats.)

Answer (score 1):

I don't personally use SymPy, but it seems you can use

```
ip_coord = [(59.7650000000000, -17.968172555939*I), (59.7650000000000, 17.968172555939*I)] 
imaginaries = list(map(
    lambda couple : couple[0] if im(couple[1]) == 0 else couple[1],
    ip_coord
))
```

Comment: what if the first coordinate is imaginary?

Comment: Ah, to be honest the question wasn't very clear... I'll edit that right now.